# C# Как преобразовать byte[] в Brush?

Tags: c#, bytearray

Есть такой код, он преобразует byte[] в Brush

```
public static Brush ByteToBrush(byte[] image)
        {
            ImageBrush brush = new ImageBrush();
            BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream(image))
            {
                bi = new BitmapImage();
                bi.BeginInit();
                bi.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None;
                bi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                bi.StreamSource = ms;
                bi.EndInit();
            }
            brush.ImageSource = bi;
            return brush;
        }
```

Как преобразовать обратно Brush в byte[]?

Comment: ээээ, а зачем? вам не должно такого хотеться. расскажите свою настоящую проблему

Comment: Просто я использую компонент Border как Image, устанавливаю картинку ему на Background, а эта картинка хранится в БД как byte[]. Я преобразую Brush Border'а в массив байтов и отправляю в БД, потом достаю оттуда и преобразовываю из byte[] в Brush и устанавливаю Background Border'а.

Comment: А зачем вам преобразовывать назад? У вас же есть массив байт, из которого вы этот Brush строили, верно?

Comment: А если вы записываете туда картинку, ну так и храните эту картинку в базе. Но не нужно пытаться сначала засунуть эту картинку в Brush, а потом выудить её оттуда — Brush вовсе не обязан хранить для вас оригинал.

Comment: Понял, спасибо.